# "The gyroelongated triangular bipyramid can be made with equilateral triangles"

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra

According to Wikipedia article [Gyroelongated bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroelongated_bipyramid)

> The gyroelongated triangular bipyramid can be made with equilateral triangles

I can only imagine that this would result in a cube, could you please explain otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image in Wikipedia's table actually shows this configuration.

[image]

If you collapse each set of coplanar sides you get something with 6 quadrilateral faces that fit together *like* a cube, but each face is a rhombus with corner angles 60-120-60-120, rather than the cube's 90-90-90-90.

You can think of it as a cube that is *stretched* along one of the long (inner) diagonals.

Comment: Im still trying to visualise this with equilateral triangles.. Maybe I will (attempt to) construct one, thank you

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense (after construction), except one thing: that with equilateral triangles it becomes 6 rhombus faces as you mention, and wikipedia states 12 faces for the Gyroelongated triangular bipyramid.

Comment: @qluto: That's because the Wikipedia table is counting _triangles_, before you merge them into rhombi.

Comment: ah.. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The triangular bipyramid you're elongating is an octahedron. The image in your link shows that when you elongate it some of the new faces are coplanar with the old ones. There are six faces, but they are not squares. @HenningMalcom 's  answer here describes those faces. This answer adds the fact that what you started with was an octahedron.

Comment: Um. There's no _icosahedron_ anywhere within sight here. The _antiprism_ you sandwich in between the triangular pyramids is an octahedron -- but the (unelongated) triangular bipyramid is not anything even an uniform polyhedron.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course. Right in the first sentence, fixed the last sentence.